# RDKit SetScale method for drawing

Tags: methods, set, scale, draw, rdkit

RDKit Chem Python tutorial is not so good. I needed the Set Scale function for drawing, but I have difficulty to understand the arguments. Although my research, I have not seen an example of use on the Internet and no description available. Thanks for your attention.

```
SetScale((MolDraw2D)arg1, (int)arg2, (int)arg3, (Point2D)arg4, (Point2D)arg5) → None :
uses the values provided to set the drawing scaling

C++ signature :
void SetScale(RDKit::MolDraw2D {lvalue},int,int,RDGeom::Point2D,RDGeom::Point2D)
```

Comment: There is a C++ example of using the SetScale function in the rdkit tests: [Here](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/master/Code/GraphMol/MolDraw2D/test1.cpp#L1558), This will not be much different to the python API, so you should be able to translate it. If you could add more context to your question and what you have tried so far it will be easier to answer.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks.